# Softmax not resulting in a probability distribution in Python Implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, softmax

I have a simple softmax implementation:

```
softmax = np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)
```

For x set as array here: https://justpaste.it/6wis7

You can load it as:

```
 import numpy as np

 x = np.as (just copy and paste the content (starting from array))
```

I get:

```
softmax.mean(axis=0).shape 
(100,) # now all elements must be 1.0 here, since its a probability

softmax.mean(axis=0) # all elements are not 1

array([0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158,
       0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158, 0.05263158])
```

Why is this implementation wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summatory of the probabilities must be 1, no it's mean. Let's make it more clear with this simple example. Imagine 3 `softmax` output values `s = [0.5, 0.25, 0.25]`. Obviously they have to sum up `1` (probability). But their mean is `0.333`.

```py
>>> softmax.sum(axis=0)
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

I hope that this example make that clear!

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me:

```
import numpy as np

def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)

logits = softmax(np.random.rand(4))

print(logits)
```

The sum of all elements of the softmax actications is supposed to equal to 1.

For classification tasks, one usually takes the index with the highest value (`np.argmax()`) or the highest n-indices and selects those as the most likely class(es):

```
class_index = np.argmax(logits)  # Assuming logits is the output of a trained model

print('Most likely class: %d' % class_index)
```

---

As pointed out by JosepJoestar in the comments, the definition of the softmax function can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function).

Comment: yes i have provided the input as well..the input is not working

Comment: @Rafael I think you're confusing how softmax works. The sum of all elements is supposed to be 1.

Comment: Yes, the code has no problems, except for the misunderstanding of how softmax works. It's clearly defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function), (first paragraph).